# Error in optimize(function(t) { : object 'th' not found

Tags: r, lme4

I'm new to glmer.nb and multilevel modeling in general.  Can anyone point me in the right direction on this error message?  As far as I've read, glmer.nb should be estimating theta from g0 with the MASS package and then using it for the glmer.nb model.  Any insight would be much appreciated. I've tried updating all my packages.

```
x1<-rbinom(750, prob=.2, size=1)
x2<-rbinom(750, prob=.15, size=1)
x3<-rbinom(750, prob=.10, size=1)
id<-seq(1,750,1)
x<-c("x1","x2","x3")
data<-data.frame(id,x1,x2,x3)
data.long <- reshape(data,idvar="id", varying=list(x), 
            v.names=c("x"), timevar="year", 
            times = c(0,1,2), direction="long")

mod <- glmer.nb(x ~ (1|id),data = data.long, na.action=na.omit, 
            interval = log(th) + c(-3, 3), verbose = FALSE)

Error in optimize(function(t) { : object 'th' not found
```

Comment: You have set `interval = log(th)` but you don't have `th` defined anywhere. What was your intention with setting that parameter?

Comment: @MrFlick Based on the lme4 descriptions, I thought glmer.nb estimates theta from a poisson model.

Comment: If you want to use the default settings, don't set the `interval=` parameter. When you set the value, R will try to resolve variables in your user environment. When set as a default value, R will attempt to resolve variables in the function enclosure. So just do `glmer.nb(x ~ (1|id),data = data.long, na.action=na.omit, verbose = FALSE)`